# Django-allauth stores an empty token_secret with linkedin_oauth2

Tags: oauth-2.0, django-allauth

I'm trying the make further requests to linkedinAPI and to do so I need both token and token_secret.

I have several test accounts in linkedin, the login process success with all of them, however the token_secret stores (for all of them is empty).

Is that an error? I suspect so because using the pair token/token_secret in subsecuent oauth2 calls I get the following from linkedin

```
{ "errorCode": 0, "message": "[unauthorized]. The token used in the OAuth request is not valid. AQVvM2f2qefU3vULPS-R46DXN8Mnra9ImG14hzeTvMMcXvBVOEiUl4RTZCJrdFZoTfGGN1fFzLvxG-O_UWB8s8EDr35ZsgwW59y4KilndoEkr105Sg2GR90jmUxpqxU572IiARjN5gxAjfoWC4-_UupKlEtafQn23XQqvXeuLvE-FsPAaSA", "requestId": "VOAL1ULK4X", "status": 401, "timestamp": 1395348629428 }
```

**Further details:**
I check these tokens using the shell:

```
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialToken
map(lambda st: st.token_secret, SocialToken.objects.all())
```

And I get empty output:

```
[u'', u'', u'']
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself so I'll explain it.

I'm not very into oauth2 so I don't know about the process neither if it was normal to have an empty secret_token. So I debugged a bit into the django-allauth code, and I saw that the requests they perform use only the token (no secret token)

Then I changed the library and started using the same they do: requests. And with the following simple script I can make any other request to the linkedin API:

```
def see_my_groups_json(request, url):    
    import requests
    token = SocialToken.objects.get(account__user_id=request.user.pk)
    resp = requests.get(url, params={'oauth2_access_token': token.token})
    return resp.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the SCOPE parameter for [linkedin](/questions/tagged/linkedin) provider. For example, the next configuration requests permission for accessing user's email address, basic profile and to read and share updates on behalf of the user.

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'linkedin_oauth2': {
        'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress', 'r_basicprofile', 'rw_nus'],
        'PROFILE_FIELDS': ['id', 'first-name', 'last-name', 'email-address', 'picture-url', 'public-profile-url']
    }
}
```

If after the token generation, we try to make an API call that requires some other privilege, we will get a 401 status code HTTP response.

[django-allauth](/questions/tagged/django-allauth), by default, r_emailaddress scope or none at all, depending on whether or not SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL is enabled.

Hope this helps you.